# Трехмерный график matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

Строю трехмерный график для функции z = (0.1 * y - sin(0.2 * x - y - 0.4)) * (2 + cos(0.7 * y - x + 2)**2) и никак не могу понять в чем ошибка.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from math import sin, cos, pi
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
ax_3d = Axes3D(fig)
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = x
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zgrid = (0.1 * y - sin(0.2 * x - y - 0.4)) * (2 + cos(0.7 * y - x + 2)**2)
ax_3d.plot_surface(xgrid, ygrid, zgrid)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас две основные ошибки - 1) вы используете скалярные функции sin и cos на массивах, 2) вы вычисляете Z не на полученных мешах, а на исходных массивах.

Для решения первой проблемы - используйте методы модуля numpy вместо методов  модуля math (он вам здесь вообще не нужен.) Для решения второй - просто подставьте в формулу верные переменные.
Ну и кроме того, вы используете устаревший способ инициализации 3d. для этого инициируйте согласно рекомендациям в документации:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
ax_3d = Axes3D(fig, auto_add_to_figure=False)
fig.add_axes(ax_3d)

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = x
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zgrid = (0.1 * y - np.sin(0.2 * xgrid - ygrid - 0.4)) * (2 + np.cos(0.7 * ygrid - xgrid + 2)**2)
ax_3d.plot_surface(xgrid, ygrid, zgrid)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо вам!